# Strange <div> position (moving around during jQuery function)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which is shown and hidden by a jQuery function. The problem is that the div "moves" around not in the center when I click the button.
Why does this happen? How can I prevent this?[image]

The HTML code (BootStrap 3):

```
<div class='input-group-btn'>
    <button type="button" id='search' class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" />
    </button>
</div>
<form method='POST' style='display:inline;'/>
<div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='genericResearch' placeholder="Cerca" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="submit" name='search' class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
</form>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method='POST'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>
                    <select name='filter' class="form-control">
                        <option value=''>Limita a...</option>
                        <option value="all">Niente / Cerca tutto</option>
                        <option value="ingrediente">Ingredienti</option>
                        <option value="componente">Componenti</option>
                        <option value="pietanza">Pietanze</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>
                    <input class="form-control" name='nome' type="text" placeholder='Nome' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name='quantity' class='form-control'>
                        <option value=''>Metodo di Confronto</option>
                        <option value='more'>Maggiore di...</option>
                        <option value='equal'>Precisamente...</option>
                        <option value='less'>Minore di...</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='number' id='quantita' class='form-control' name='qvalue' placeholder='Quantità' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name='search' class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$("#search").click(function(){
    $("#adv-search").toggle(1000);
});
```

The CSS code:

```
.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
}
.input-group-btn .btn-group {
    display: flex !important;
}
.btn-group .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-group .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.form-group .form-control:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #adv-search {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
        position: static !important;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 500px;
    }
}
```

Comment: please include an example. You seem to be missing your custom css code which is crucial in finding the problem.

Comment: OK, I'll post also my CSS search code

Comment: The reason for that is because you are using toggle(1000), and 1000 refers to how long the animation will run. you can either use 0 instead of 1000 or show() and hide().

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `$("#adv-search").toggle(1000);` displays the element progressively causing its width to change during the appearance, what your browser does is to center the element when it starts appearing then when the width stops changing it adjusts the element position

**EDIT :** the html code that you posted is messy you have some mismatching tags 
for example you are using an empty form tag

```
<form method='POST' style='display:inline' />
```

Comment: Yes man, you're perfectly right, this code is a huge mess, but this is just because I'm still doing lots of experiments on the run, I'm gonna clean everything once finished XD

Comment: so you're telling me that there's no solution for this problem at all? :'(

Comment: don't do several experiments at once, it can be confusing